# Optimization in Unity GameObject method calls

Tags: unity-game-engine

Releasing game to Prod

I am finished with all components of my game and now I am wondering if it is okay to use `FindObjectofType` too much? will there be a bad result of using this method?

I tried using `FindObjectOftype` method in everywhere whenever I need don't know if it will affect the performance of game or not

Comment: It depends. Do it a few times and it's probably not an issue, but do it many times every frame and that's a sign you should be caching the result. The profiler is the tool to use to see what's taking the most time in your game. Optimize the hotspots and keep profiling until you don't have any more or you meet the target you have in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually ok to use that method. But do not use these methods in Update(). consider using it in Start or Awake method.. According to Unity's 'General Optimizations' you should avoid using  'Object.FindObjectOfType' method in production. Since this method requesting UnityEngine to iterate over all GameObjects and Components in memory. Which will cause undesirable drain on performance.